# Why does \n mess up my column in C++ after using setw()?

Tags: c++, setw

Im in College and one of our projects in our software programing class was to prompt the user to input five different test scores, after which the program will calculate the average and display the individual scores along with the average in columns. i had an issue where setw(10) was displaying the proper spacing for everything except for the string "average".

i have since fixed this but was curious as to why my fix worked.

the original code was as follows:

```cpp
cout << "\n\n" << setw(10) << "Test 1" << setw(10) << "Test 2" << setw(10) << "Test 3"
     << setw(10) << "Test 4" << setw(10) << "Test 5" << setw(10) << "Average\n\n";
```

its output looked like this:

```
    Test 1    Test 2    Test 3    Test 4    Test 5 Average

      77.0      78.0      89.0      87.0      67.0     79.60
```

i then deleted the \n's i had at the end and just put endl after the string and it was fixed:

```
    Test 1    Test 2    Test 3    Test 4    Test 5   Average
      78.0      78.0      67.0      78.0      56.0     71.40
```

what does \n do to mess with the spacing after using setw()?

Comment: The shown code can't result in the shown output. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What version of C++ can you use? If it is C++20 you should use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) instead. It is much more easy to align output using that (columns widths can be set and column content can even be left/middle/right aligned)

Comment: The positioning is calculated based on the length of the string `"Average\n\n"`, which is 9. Compare with the string `"Average"`, which has a width of 7.

Comment: Pepijn, thanks for the tip, but our professore insists we use setprecision and setw for now. we are only allowed to include <iostream> and <iomainip> and our header file.

Comment: @237K everything that was relevant to answer the question was included. no one needs to reproduce my code to help me understand how setw() works.

Comment: @ManguyFlame Ask your professor if it is okay to use format. Using setw/precission should not make any difference in what you learn about C++ (only that the training material is probably a bit out of date by now). In the end I think he should be up-to-date and teach you guys "current C++"

Comment: The reason it "worked" when you (mistakenly) switched to `std::endl` is that you changed the format of the output statement. Make the analogous change without `std::endl`, that is, change `"Average\n\n"` to `"Average" << "\n\n"`.

Comment: Just for funsies,  because `setw` counts **char** it will run into the same kind of issue with UTF-8 encoded string literals, `"Åvérägè"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does \n do to mess with the spacing after using setw()?

Of course, it does nothing.

Look it at from the computer's point of view. The string `"Average\n\n"` has length 9. It does not matter that the final two characters are whitespace. The length is still 9.

Your program asks the computer to output a string of length 9 in a field of width 10. So the computer outputs a single space, and then outputs `"Average\n\n"`, expecting that the padding will effectively right-align the string.

When you delete the two newline characters, the string length is shortened to 7. Now, the computer outputs 3 spaces of padding, and then the string `"Average"`. This has the effect of right-aligning the string in a field that is 10 characters wide.